# Error Solicitud CORS JSON AJAX JQUERY

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web la cual actualiza datos cada 1 segundo por una función Jquery  , en la cual envio datos por ajax y me devuelve un JSON  en el cual muestro los datos en un elemento div. Todo anda bien cuando lo ejecuto desde mi localhost pero al momento de ejecutarlo desde otro cliente dentro de la misma red , el navegador me muestra el error "Solicitud CORS no exitosa"(Tambien ocurre lo mismo si lo subo a un hosting). He intentado miles de formas pero no he encontrado solución.

Este es mi HTML : En el `<tbody id="data_cupos">` es donde cargo los datos que obtengo desde un objeto JSON

```
    <?php
include ('includes/header.php');  
require_once ('../clases/Alumno.php');
require_once ('../clases/Curso.php');
require_once ('../clases/Taller.php');


$alumno = new Alumno();
$datos = $alumno->obtenerAlumnosRut($_SESSION['s_id']);


for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos);$i++){
    $id_alumno = $datos[$i]['id_alumno'];
    $nombre = $datos[$i]['primer_nombre'];
    $segundo_nombre = $datos[$i]['segundo_nombre'];
    $apellido_paterno = $datos[$i]['apellido_paterno'];
    $curso = $datos[$i]['curso'];
    $nivel = $datos[$i]['nivel'];
    $seccion = $datos[$i]['seccion'];


    $id_curso = $datos[$i]['id_curso_f'];
}

$datos_a_t = $alumno->obtenerTallerAlumno($id_alumno);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos_a_t);$i++){
    $nombre_taller = $datos_a_t[$i]['nombre_taller'];
}

$taller = new Taller();
$datos_taller =$taller->comprobarTaller($id_alumno);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos_taller);$i++){
    $switch = $datos_taller[$i]['switch'];
}


$objeto_curso = new Curso();
$datos2 = $objeto_curso->obtenerTalleresPorCurso($id_curso);


?>

<?php if($switch==0){?>
<h2 class="h3 text-gray-800">Bienvenid@ <?php echo $nombre." ".$segundo_nombre." ".$apellido_paterno." ".$curso."° ".$nivel." ".$seccion; ?></h2>

<div class="card shadow mb-4">

    <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"> <?php echo $datos2[$i]["horario"];?></h4>
                </div>
                    <select name="id_curso" id="id_curso" hidden>
                        <option value="<?php echo $id_curso?>"></option>
                    </select>
                <tr>
                    <th>Taller</th>
                    <th>Cupos</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Seleccionar</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php $datos2 = $objeto_curso->obtenerTalleresPorCurso($id_curso);?>
                <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos2);$i++){?>        
                <tbody id="data_cupos">
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="miModal<?php echo $datos2[$i]["id_t_c"];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Recordatorio</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="../procesos/talleres_cursos.php?id=<?php echo $datos2[$i]["id_taller"];?>&id_alumno=<?php echo $id_alumno;?>"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Aceptar</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php }?>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }else{?>
    <h2 class="h3 text-gray-800">Bienvenid@ <?php echo $nombre." ".$segundo_nombre." ".$apellido_paterno." ".$curso."° ".$nivel." ".$seccion; ?></h2>
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="text-center">
        <img class="img-fluid px-3 px-sm-4 mt-3 mb-4" style="width: 25rem;" src="../img/write-paper-ink.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Te has inscrito en el taller de <?php echo $nombre_taller?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>    




<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/interval.js"></script>




<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Este es mi archivo JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    listar(); 
    setInterval(function(){
        listar(); 
    },1000)
});

function listar(){
    __ajax()
    .done(function(info){
        //console.log(info);
        var talleres_cupos = JSON.parse(info);
        var html = "";
        //console.log(talleres_cupos);

        for(var i in talleres_cupos.data){
            html+=

                "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+talleres_cupos.data[i].nombre_taller+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+talleres_cupos.data[i].cupos+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='text-center'>"+"<a style='color:white' id='btn_inscribir' data-toggle='modal' class='btn "+talleres_cupos.data[i].boton+" ' data-target='#miModal"+talleres_cupos.data[i].id_t_c+"'>"+talleres_cupos.data[i].boton_mensaje+"</a> "+"</td>"
                +"</tr>"

        }

        $("#data_cupos").html(html);
    });
}

function __ajax(){
    var cursoID = $("#id_curso").val();

        if(cursoID){
            var ajax = $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/acle/js/fetch.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: 'curso_id='+cursoID                
            })
        }

        return ajax;
}
```

Este es  el PHP que hace la consulta a la BD y hace el json_encode

```
<?php
require_once ('../clases/Conexion.php');




$conexion = new Conexion();
$cnn =$conexion->conectar();


$curso_id = $_POST["curso_id"];


$query ="SELECT `id_curso`,id_t_c,talleres.nombre as nombre_taller,talleres_cursos.cupos as cupos,talleres.id_taller as id_taller,if(talleres_cursos.cupos=0,'disabled btn-danger','btn-success') as boton,if(talleres_cursos.cupos=0,'Sin cupos','Inscribir Taller') as boton_mensaje
FROM `talleres_cursos`
INNER JOIN talleres
ON talleres_cursos.id_taller =talleres.id_taller
WHERE talleres_cursos.id_curso = '$curso_id'";   
$consultar = mysqli_query($cnn,$query);

        while($dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultar)){
            $data["data"][]=$dado;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Finalmente cuando ejecuto desde el localhost el resultado es este 
[image: img]

Pero desde un cliente ocurre esto
[image: img]

Comment: te sugiero revisar bien la url de tu ajax  "http://localhost/acle/js/fetch.php" .. es decir no la apuntes asi como localhost sino al archivo algo asi: "../../acle/js/fetch.php"

Comment: claro para eso debes ver como esta la estructura de tus archivos y carpetas

Comment: Hola , si lo he intentado pero cuando no pongo la ruta absoluta el ajax no me funciona, y tengo el archivo fetch.php dentro de la misma carpeta del ajax.

Comment: si esta dentro de la misma carpeta tanto el js como el php solo deberias poner el nombre de tu archivo como url  algo asi: url: 'fetch.php'....con eso seria todo en teoria

Comment: así es , pongo solo el nombre del archivo tal cual como lo mencionas y el ajax deja de funcionar por completo , por eso decidí hacerlo con la ruta absoluta que es de la única forma que me funciona.

Comment: podrias agregar dentro de tu archivo "fetch.php"..lo siguiente: header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

Comment: Si bro fue lo primero que hice, también subi el proyecto a un hosting y  lo agregue en el htaccess y el problema persiste

Comment: Te sucede el mismo problema en otros navegadores? te sugiero que le eches un vistazo a este [post](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/6679424) que trata el mismo problema, y [aquí](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/) la aparente solución

Comment: Hola , si ya he probado con todos los navegadores , ahora estoy haciendo pruebas en el hosting y he agregado los headers en el .htaccess y aun así el problema persiste .